# How do I cascade delete a polymorphic table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

What I would like to do is every time I delete a ThoughtRecord I want to delete the comments that polymorphically belong to that ThoughtRecord.

**ThoughtRecordController**

```
public function destroy(ThoughtRecord $thoughtRecord)
{
    $thoughtRecord->delete();
}
```

**ThoughtRecord Model**

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

**Comment Model**

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**ThoughtRecord Table**

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->boolean('is_authorized')->default(false);
$table->string('title')->nullable();
$table->timestamps();
```

**Comment Table**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('commentable_id');
$table->string('commentable_type');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->text('content');
$table->timestamps();
```

Comment: Your model design is wrong.

Comment: How is it wrong? My comments have polymorphic relations with other models.

Answer (score 4):

**One option:**

Manage cascade deletes with this package:

[Package for manage cascade deletes](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-cascade-deletes)

**Second Option:**

You Could Listen To An Events That Laravel Provide

```
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

            // cause a delete of a poster to cascade
            // to children so they are also deleted
            static::deleting(function ($poster) {

                            $photos->photos->delete();

                        $poster->comments()->delete();

            });

    }
```

**Third Option:**

When you are using a polymorphic relationship you probably also use it a Trait. If that's the case you can delete the relations in the boot method of the trait by hooking in to deleting event.

```
<?php namespace Company\Package\Traits;

/**
 * This file is part of Package.
 *
 * @license MIT
 * @package Company\Package
 */

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

trait ActionableTrait
{
    /**
     * Morph Many relation with Task.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Config::get('crm.action'),'actionable');
    }

    protected static function bootActionableTrait()
    {
        self::deleting(function ($model) {
            $model->actions()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

**Option four:**

Just simple code , Override delete method on Your model. If this model is deleted , delete other associated models.

```
public function delete()
{
       $res=parent::delete();
       if($res==true)
       {
                $relations=$this->youRelation; // here get the relation data
                // delete Here
    }
}
```

read it https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-polymorphic-relationships

Comment: Option 3 is clever and looks clean to me, going with that! Did not now about the `bootTrait` hook. Thanks! :)